# Python upgrade in the system creates issue in virtualenv -- not find platform independent libraries

Tags: python, ubuntu

I upgraded from `Ubuntu 14.04` to `Ubuntu 16.04` and the `python3` changed from `3.4.3` to `3.5.2`. (I am using `64 bit` Ubuntu) I had a virtual environment using python3. Now when I go to that environment and try to run my Flask application or even use pip it gives error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

- I suspect it happened because of python upgrade. Am I right?

On option is to rebuild the environment again with new python and reinstall packages for that environment but I had other environments as well.

- What can I do to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you sure you are in your virtual environment?  It should still be using the python you created when you created the virtualenv.

Comment: Me, I'd rebuild the virtualenvs. 3.5 is a nicer version of Python anyway.

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file? If you have a virtualenv it would take about a minute to set up a new one to try to fix the issue. Is python 3.4 a requirement? You should be able to set up the virtualenv using -p `which python34` if you want 3.4

Comment: @joelgoldstick yup i am sure I am in python. I created virutalenv by `mkvirualenv --python==/usr/local/python3 virualenvname`.

Comment: @user3154952 making a new virtual environment is no problem. But all my previous ones are not working. I dont have requirements.txt sadly.

Comment: @WayneWerner yup thats what i am doing right now.