# Having issue with python pip command

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I had python pip installed and it was working fine but I did something wrong now it is broken.

Now when I execute pip command to install new packages, I get an error.

like if execute `pip list` then I get the below error.

```
root@dragonwarrior-Latitude-3440:~# pip list 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4, >in <module>
    import locale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 15, in <module>
    import encodings
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

Comment: Are you in a virtualenv? I had a similar problem when my Ubuntu Python upgraded to 3.5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751662/python-upgrade-in-the-system-creates-issue-in-virtualenv-not-find-platform-in

Comment: "but I did something wrong now it is broken" - would help if you elaborated on that.

Comment: even if i am in virtualenv i get the same error

Comment: Which version of pip are you using? Is it python 2 / 3? It is probably a path problem

Comment: I am not sure what I did that is causing the problem

Comment: pip freeze is giving the same error

Comment: I had the same issue, when my ubuntu upgrade python to 3.5 all my virtualenvs crashed. I did know how to fix them, so I had to make my virtualenvs again.

Comment: I think your python path is not set properly. https://techglimpse.com/error-executing-python3-5-command-solution/